# Android Retrofit Post Issue

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I previously implemented the following post request with volley but now i want to use it for retrofit.
So my rest webservice is the following
www.blahblahblah.com/webservice.svc/

I have a function (Person) that is called in the webservice that accepts the following jsonobject

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject searchCriteria = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("FullName", "frank jones");
jsonObject.put("DOB", "06-04-1978");
jsonObject.put("Age", "28");
jsonObject.put("Reason", "Search");
searchCriteria.put("searchCriteria", jsonObject);
```

So in volley i call www.blahblahblah.com/webservice.svc/Person
and pass the above jsonobject. 
Works perfectly

So for Retrofit i've used the same logic, create my jsonobject and pass it in the request
So i use the same url www.blahblahblah.com/webservice.svc/

Create my Post

```
@POST("Person")
Call<PersonResponseData> getPersonAccess(@Body Object body);
```

so then my code to get the response

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(urlSearch)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);

    Call<PersonResponseData> personResponseDataCall =        service.getPersonAccess(searchCriteria);

    personResponseDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<PersonResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<PersonResponseData> response,    Retrofit retrofit) {
            int statuscode = response.code();
            PersonResponseData personResponseData = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

I just get a 404 error, any ideas.
As i said this works perfectly in volley but I've done something wrong in retrofit.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can review this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373921/whats-wrong-with-this-retrofit-call#39374659) here is a explanation for use `retrofit 2` with `POST request`

Answer (score 0):

That's only guess, but try following:
1) in Call declaration specify it, not `Call getPersonAccess`, but `Call<PersonResponseData> getPersonAccess`;
2) make POJO instead of JSON object and use it as a body instead of passing Object into `getPersonAccess` call.